# Smooth playback of .mkv files incorrectly rated at 29fps

Tags: matroska, video-playback, media-player-classic, framerate

I noticed for some mkv files, the frame reported in Explorer and VLC is 29, but this is incorrect as it's actually a 24fps source (i.e. Blu-Ray movie), and the file plays with judder in MPC-HC and VLC. If I force the refresh rate of the TV to 24hz, the judder becomes extreme and unwatchable. I'm not exactly sure what's wrong with the file.

Generally I don't have issues with getting smooth playback at 24hz, using MPC-HC and madvr. The file is recognized as 24fps, MPC-HC automatically switches the resolution to 24hz and all is good. It seems to be an issue only with some .mkv files. Is it possible to fix this in the file header? Or somehow force playback at a steady 24fps anyway?

Comment: what codec are they using? x624/HEVC-8bit/etc. does VLC indicate that hardware acceleration is in use?

Comment: Was h.264. Not sure about HW acceleration but this is not a performance issue, I can play 4K or high bit-rate HEVC just fine.